# Set width and height of object inheriting from frame class in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter, frames

I am trying to build a GUI calculator with tabbed pages using tkk.Notebook. The different pages consist of objects inheriting from the ttk.Frame widget. I am able to create the frames but they end up being very small and the widgets I have placed on them overlap and impede on each other. Using the width and height options with the frames does not seem to change the dimensions at all either. I am fairly new to object oriented programming, so I think the issue has to do with how I am creating the frames, but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

class DimFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)


        self.length_label = ttk.Label(self, text='Length: ')
        self.length_label.grid(row=0)
        self.length = float()
        self.length_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.length, width=10)
        self.length_entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

    ...more methods and widgets, etc...

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1000x500')

    s = ttk.Style()

    style = ThemedStyle(root)
    style.set_theme('black')

    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    notebook.grid()

    dimensions_frame = DimFrame(root)

    dimensions_frame.grid()

    notebook.add(dimensions_frame, text='Room Dimensions')

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try: `<tk.Frame>.grid_propagate(False)`. Also add `height=..., width=...` in the `super().__init__(master)`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you that worked! This helped me to fix the frame dimensions and I realized I had accidentally given the wrong column numbers which was causing certain widgets to overlap. Thanks again!

Comment: `grid_propagate(False)` is almost always the wrong thing to do. Tkinter is very good at making frames just big enough to fit their contents. You should give us a [mcve] which we can run, so we can identify the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the input. It turned out my problem was entirely formatting on my part and grid_propagate(False) was not necessary to rectify the problem